# How to find a valley after FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

After FFT ([here is the input data and output images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/49gy6uhfsfplgzt/AADw-M8UOsUX2XxQyuJknJkaa?dl=0)) I need to find the valley between two peaks and its position on x axis (see figure 1).

Because I interested only in two main peaks and the valley between them I may take only part of the data showed on the figure 1:

```
b_border = round(1500*length(fq)/fmax);
t_border = round(4000*length(fq)/fmax);
```

I tried to use findpeaks but unfortunately there are a lot of small peaks and valleys so that I get wrong results. Please see figures 2 and 3.

Here is the code:

```
fy=fft(y);
L=length(y);
L2=round(L/2);
fa=abs(fy(1:L2));
fmax=Fs/2;
fq=((0:L2-1)/L2)*fmax;
figure;
plot(fq,fa);

b_border = round(1500*length(fq)/fmax);
t_border = round(4000*length(fq)/fmax);
plot(fq(b_border:t_border),fa(b_border:t_border));
```

What might be the right solution?
I very hope for your help, thanks!

Comment: you want the 2 major peaks, so findpeaks is the correct way to go, all you have to do is to select the 2 largest peaks from your findpeaks result.

Comment: yes, i think i can do that, but i don't know how to find the valley between them, because there are small values like noise :( please see figure 3.png

Comment: yeah, this is exactly the point where you want to smooth the reading using some periodigram modification method, like Welch method or power spectrum (power density spectrum). Check this out: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have found a solution:

```
rangeSize = 75;
maximums = [,];
for i=b_border:rangeSize:t_border
    [fr, ind] = max(fa(i:i+rangeSize-1));
    maximums = [maximums; fr ind];
end

[low_a, ind2] = min(maximums(:,1), [], 1);
```

Also before to find a minimum might to apply some filter for smoothing